# Trying to make optimistic locking to work in Grails with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, jpa

I found optimistic locking is not working for me in my small demo Grails app with hibernate domain class. The domain class is simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DELME", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID"))

public class DelmeV implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int id;
    private Long version;
    private String d2;
    private String dsc;

    // ... constructors goes here
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {...}
    public void setId(int id) {...}

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public Long getVersion() { ... }
    public void setVersion(Long version) { ... }

    @Column(name = "D2")
    // appropriate getters and setters goes here ...

    @Column(name = "DSC") 
    // appropriate getters and setters goes here ...

}
```

Controller code is scaffolded:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class DelmeVController {

// methods which are out of interest skipped... 
@Transactional
def update(DelmeV delmeVInstance) {
    if (delmeVInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (delmeVInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond delmeVInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    delmeVInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'DelmeV.label', default: 'DelmeV'), delmeVInstance.id])
            redirect controller:"delmeV", id:delmeVInstance.id
        }
        '*'{ respond delmeVInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}
}
```

The testing procedure is following:

1. Run grails application, take Delme row with given id (say, 1) into edit form.
2. Do the "sql update delme set d2='bad value', version=version+1 where id=1;" on the database server.
3. Do the "sql select * from delme where id=1;" on the database server and verify that d2 has value set in step 2 and version is actually incremented.
4. Change DSC field value in the opened edit form and hit "update" button.
5. Result: update goes smoothly, D2 value set in step 2 goes to nowhere silently, no exceptions happens. Bad.

So, **Question 1**: what's wrong above? Why optimistic locking is not working out of the box for me?

Well, I surrendered with default optimistic locking behaviour and wrote my own (considering that our actual business tables doesn't have 'version' columns and pessimistic lock is not an option in OLTP env):
I made 'version' transient, filled it in onLoad method and checked in preUpdate:

```
@Entity
@Table(...) 

public class DelmeV  implements org.hibernate.classic.Lifecycle {
  // unisteresting stuff...

  @Transient
  private String version;
  // getters, setters ...

  public void onLoad (Session s, java.io.Serializable id) {
    if (this != null) {
      try {
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper om = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
        om.configure (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        this.version = om.writeValueAsString (this);
      } catch (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException e) {
         System.out.println ("Jackson exception caught on #" + this.id);
         e.printStackTrace();
         this.version = "/x/";
     }
   }

   @javax.persistence.PreUpdate
   public void actualOnUpdate (Session s) throws StaleObjectStateException {

     SessionFactory sessionFactory = s.getSessionFactory();
     Session ns = null;
     Object newInstance = null;
     String dbVersion = null;

     try  {
       ns = sessionFactory.openSession();
       Transaction tx = ns.beginTransaction ();
       newInstance =   ns.get (this.getClass(), this.id);
       dbVersion = ((DelmeV) newInstance).getVersion();
       tx.commit();
     } catch (Throwable ex) {
       System.out.println ("Session creation exception caught on " + this.getClass().getName() + ", id=" + this.id);
       ex.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
       ns.close();
     }
   boolean eq = dbVersion.equals (this.version);
   if (!eq) {
     throw new StaleObjectStateException (this.getClass().getName(), this.id);
   }
 }
}
```

I registered event listeners which scan domain class for @preUpdate method and call it as long as Grails doesn't call it automatically. So far so good, solution is working, but it happened to be incompatible with other frameworks (Spring Batch, specifically) as JPA requires @preUpdate method to be with empty argument list and I have no idea how to figure out current Session or SessionFactory (or EntityManagerFactory, as long as JPA involved) from preUpdate method (in Grails I passed Session as parameter invoking preUpdate method from event listener). So **Question 2**: How to figure out Session/SessionFactory/EntityManagerFactory from domain method in consistent, framework independent way?

Comment: Updating the data directly via the database is the issue. Hibernate is using it's own cache to compare the previous cached version with the newly updated version and seeing everything is okay. Turn off the Hibernate cache if you are going to be doing updates directly to the database and not only through Hibernate. When you circumvent the system, the system doesn't work. That's your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but how can it be done? I tried to set  cache.use_second_level_cache = false, cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory', cache.provider = 'org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider' in DataSource.groovy and @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE) in the domain class. Neither helped.

Comment: I think StatelessSession could help here, but I have no idea how to configure Grails to use it. The digging is continuing...